# How to render components on click plus without changing the 'state'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im not too experienced with react and I have a question. I wanted to have a component that has a nav bar and based on what is clicked-that component is rendered - BUT where the navbar stays (so the other component is being displayed below the navbar). My code does just that but I don't understand why. Could someone explain why when in my code, when I click for example on 'first', the search component is still displayed and below it my first component is rendered? Why won't only the first page being rendered? Thanks a lot!!

```
class App extends React.Component {
                render () {
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Switch>                     
                                <Route path='/first' component={BudgetSearch}/>
                                <Route path='/second' component={CheapestFareForDestination}/>
                            </Switch>
                    <Search />
                        </div>
                   )
                }
         }

export default App;
```

Search.jsx

```
class Search extends React.Component {
            render () {

                return (
                    <div>

                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to='/first'>first</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to='/second'>second</Link></li>                          
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `<Search />` component is not being wrapped by any `<Route />` component. In essence, you're telling React that it should render `<Search />` regardless of what route gets matched by the router. So whether your routes matches `/first`, `/second` or any other route, React will still render `<Search />` because it "matches" all routes.

Comment: If you want to hide it any point, make sure `<Search />` gets wrapped by a `<Route />` component.

Answer (score 2):

Change your App code to

```
class App extends React.Component {
                render () {
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Switch> 
                                <Route path='/' component={Search}/>                    
                                <Route path='/first' component={BudgetSearch}/>
                                <Route path='/second' component={CheapestFareForDestination}/>
                            </Switch>

                        </div>
                   )
                }
         }

export default App;
```

This will render the search component when you are at the root of your application. But when you click on `first` or `second` it will navigate to the appropriate component and the Search component will not show any longer.

Previously, even though you were routing to the `first` or `second` components, you were always rendering the Search component inside your App component. This resulted in the Search component always showing up.